# Transform BASE64 string to BASE16(HEX) string?

Tags: c

Hey, I'm trying to write a program to convert from a BASE64 string to a BASE16(HEX) string.

Here's an example:

```
     BASE64:   Ba7+Kj3N
HEXADECIMAL:   05 ae fe 2a 3d cd
     BINARY:   00000101 10101110 11111110 00101010 00111101 11001101
    DECIMAL:   5 174 254 42 61 205
```

What's the logic to convert from BASE64 to HEXIDECIMAL?
Why is the decimal representation split up?
How come the binary representation is split into 6 section?

Just want the math, the code I can handle just this process is confusing me. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh, what's the difference? If so, can someone move it there or I'll just repost it.

Comment: BTW, you are aware that the hex, binary, and decimal numbers "in six sections" represent the same six numbers, right? The real question is why isn't the base-64 example "split up" as well. To answer this homework, we'd need to know the base-64 encoding: what represents the digits from 10-63? [Probably starts with a-z, but then what?]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a function listing that will convert between any two bases: https://sites.google.com/site/computersciencesourcecode/conversion-algorithms/base-to-base

---

Edit (Hopefully to make this completely clear...)

You can find more information on this at the [Wikipedia entry for Base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

The customary character set used for base 64, which is different than the character set you'll find in the link I provided prior to the edit, is:

`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/`

The character 'A' is the value 0, 'B' is the value 1, 'C' is the value 2, ...'8' is the value 60, '9' is the value 61, '+' is the value 62, and '/' is the value 63.  This character set is very different from what we're used to using for binary, octal, base 10, and hexadecimal, where the first character is '0', which represents the value 0, etc.

Soju noted in the comments to this answer that each base 64 digit requires 6 bits to represent it in binary.  Using the base 64 number provided in the original question and converting from base 64 to binary we get:

```
B        a        7        +        K        j        3        N
000001   011010   111011   111110   001010   100011   110111   001101
```

Now we can push all the bits together (the spaces are only there to help humans read the number):

```
000001011010111011111110001010100011110111001101
```

Next, we can introduce new white-space delimiters every four bits starting with the *Least Significant Bit*:

```
0000  0101  1010  1110  1111  1110  0010  1010  0011  1101  1100  1101
```

It should now be very easy to see how this number is converted to base 16:

```
0000  0101  1010  1110  1111  1110  0010  1010  0011  1101  1100  1101
0     5     A     E     F     E     2     A     3     D     C     D
```

Comment: Thanks for the link sir. So I have to decode BASE64 -> BASE10 and then to whatever base I want? Gotcha :)

Comment: @Soju: If you understand the principle, it will be trivial to convert to/from any arbitrary base. Conversion to binary is the best, because it has a direct representation.

Comment: That's the exact thing I'm having trouble with. If I'm scanning each BASE64 character one at a time how do I get from BASE64 to its binary representation?

Comment: @soju: Ask this:  How many bits does it take to represent the decimal value 63?  Once you answer that, then converting between base 64 and base 2 is elementary.

Comment: I have no idea, that's why I'm on stackoverflow.  
  
edit: 1 byte = 8 bits, 1 byte holds one character? So 16 bits? How does that help?

Comment: @soju: The base 10 number 3 is binary 11.  The base 10 number 7 is binary 111.  The base 10 number 15 is binary 1111.  The base 10 number 31 is binary 11111.  How do you write the base 10 number 63 in binary?  How many binary digits (bits) did you use?

Comment: I used 6, 111111? I'm not drawing a connection.

Comment: @soju: ...so with 6 bits you can make any number between 0 to 63 (inclusive) --64 different values.  Or in other words, 64 different characters.  Coincidentally, base 64 uses 64 different characters to represent the values 0 through 63.  Each base 64 character has a unique pattern of 6 bits.

Comment: @soju: I've edited my answer, adding all the steps needed to convert from base 64 down to base 2, then back up to base 16.  Hopefully this makes all the steps perfectly clear.

Comment: @soju:  Did the edits to the answer help you or do you still have questions?

Comment: Yeah I understand the process, but I really have trouble understanding all the bits and bytes parts of it haha. Also in my program, if I 40 B64 digits, it would be ridiculous converting that to binary and then to b16. What I'm thinking of doing is taking each B64 digit, converting it to their hex equivalent, storing that in an array cell and then outputting it all. Also, thanks for the time you took, I can honestly I say I do have a better understanding, just need to study is all.

Comment: @soju: You can store each B64 digit, like you mentioned, or you can stream it.  Every 2 B64 digits can convert exactly to 3 hex digits.  The conversion is straightforward if you start from the least significant B64 digit.  If you start from the most significant B64 digit you first have to know if there are an odd or even number of digits, otherwise all your hex digits may be shifted by 4 bits.

Answer (score 0):

think of base-64 as base(2^6)
so in order to get alignment with a hex nibble you need at least 2 base 64 digits...

with 2 base-64 digits you have a base-(2^12) number, which could be represented by 3 2^4 digits...

```
(00)(01)(02)(03)(04)(05)---(06)(07)(08)(09)(10)(11) (base-64) maps directly to:

(00)(01)(02)(03)---(04)(05)(06)(07)---(08)(09)(10)(11) (base 16)
```

so you can either convert to contiguous binary... or use 4 operations... the operations could deal with binary values, or they could use a set of look up tables (which could work on the char encoded digits):

1. first base-64 digit to first hex digit
2. first base-64 digit to first half of second hex digit
3. second base-64 digit to second half of second hex digit
4. second base-64 digit to third hex digit.

the advantage of this is that you can work on encoded bases without binary conversion.
it is pretty easy to do in a stream of chars... I am not aware of this actually being implemented anywhere though.